# For a bounded system, is potential energy positive or negative? Why?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions

Total mechanical energy is negative. Kinetic energy is 0. Therefore potential energy must be negative. Is it?

Comment: In gravitational fields, potential energy is by definition always negative, unless you are at infinity, where it is 0.

Comment: What does it mean to say "total mechanical energy is negative"? The point where potential energy is zero is an *arbitrary choice*!

Answer (score 1):

No, for a bound system the total energy is lower than the highest potential barrier.

In a gravitational or electromagnetic attractive field, the potential looks like just $\propto -\frac{1}{r}$, so it is always negative and it tends to $0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty $. Hence, if you are bound in such a system, your energy must be less than $0$, for it it were not then you'd be free (!), so your total energy is negative as well.

If you are an alpha particle in the nucleus you are still bound, even though the total energy is positive. That's because the potential now is strong force + Coulomb. The Coulomb barrier is higher than $0$ in this case:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this question a matter of definition? I agree with you that within the standard definitions your answer is correct, but in principle one could redefine the potential and make everything positive/negative in both cases, right? I just want to point out that the sign has no absolute physical meaning here I guess...

Comment: Classical and quantum mechanics do not care about shifts in absolute energy, so yes, you're right. However, GR does care, so I would always be a bit careful.